# Add attention layer to Seq2Seq model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, nlp, machine-translation

I have build a Seq2Seq model of encoder-decoder. I want to add an attention layer to it. I tried adding attention layer [through this](https://www.kaggle.com/residentmario/seq-to-seq-rnn-models-attention-teacher-forcing) but it didn't help.

Here is my initial code without attention

```
# Encoder
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
enc_emb =  Embedding(num_encoder_tokens, latent_dim, mask_zero = True)(encoder_inputs)
encoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_lstm(enc_emb)
# We discard `encoder_outputs` and only keep the states.
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
dec_emb_layer = Embedding(num_decoder_tokens, latent_dim, mask_zero = True)
dec_emb = dec_emb_layer(decoder_inputs)
# We set up our decoder to return full output sequences,
# and to return internal states as well. We don't use the
# return states in the training model, but we will use them in inference.
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(dec_emb,
                                     initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

# Define the model that will turn
# `encoder_input_data` & `decoder_input_data` into `decoder_target_data`
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
model.summary()
```

And this is the code after I added attention layer in decoder (the encoder layer is same as in initial code)

```
# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
dec_emb_layer = Embedding(num_decoder_tokens, latent_dim, mask_zero = True)
dec_emb = dec_emb_layer(decoder_inputs)
# We set up our decoder to return full output sequences,
# and to return internal states as well. We don't use the
# return states in the training model, but we will use them in inference.
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
attention = dot([decoder_lstm, encoder_lstm], axes=[2, 2])
attention = Activation('softmax')(attention)
context = dot([attention, encoder_lstm], axes=[2,1])
decoder_combined_context = concatenate([context, decoder_lstm])
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_combined_context(dec_emb,
                                     initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

# Define the model that will turn
# `encoder_input_data` & `decoder_input_data` into `decoder_target_data`
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
model.summary()
```

While doing this, I got an error

```
 Layer dot_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.layers.recurrent.LSTM'>. Full input: [<keras.layers.recurrent.LSTM object at 0x7f8f77e2f3c8>, <keras.layers.recurrent.LSTM object at 0x7f8f770beb70>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

Can someone please help in fitting an attention layer in this architecture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the dot products need to be computed on tensor outputs... in encoder you correctly define the encoder_output, in decoder you have to add `decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(enc_emb, initial_state=encoder_states)`

the dot products now are

```
attention = dot([decoder_outputs, encoder_outputs], axes=[2, 2])
attention = Activation('softmax')(attention)
context = dot([attention, encoder_outputs], axes=[2,1])
```

the concatenation doesn't need initial_states. you have to define it in your rnn layer: `decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(enc_emb, initial_state=encoder_states)`

here the full example

ENCODER + DECODER

```
# dummy variables
num_encoder_tokens = 30
num_decoder_tokens = 10
latent_dim = 100

encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
enc_emb =  Embedding(num_encoder_tokens, latent_dim, mask_zero = True)(encoder_inputs)
encoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_lstm(enc_emb)
# We discard `encoder_outputs` and only keep the states.
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
dec_emb_layer = Embedding(num_decoder_tokens, latent_dim, mask_zero = True)
dec_emb = dec_emb_layer(decoder_inputs)
# We set up our decoder to return full output sequences,
# and to return internal states as well. We don't use the
# return states in the training model, but we will use them in inference.
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(dec_emb,
                                     initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

# Define the model that will turn
# `encoder_input_data` & `decoder_input_data` into `decoder_target_data`
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
model.summary()
```

DECODER w\ ATTENTION

```
# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
dec_emb_layer = Embedding(num_decoder_tokens, latent_dim, mask_zero = True)
dec_emb = dec_emb_layer(decoder_inputs)
# We set up our decoder to return full output sequences,
# and to return internal states as well. We don't use the
# return states in the training model, but we will use them in inference.
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(dec_emb, initial_state=encoder_states)
attention = dot([decoder_outputs, encoder_outputs], axes=[2, 2])
attention = Activation('softmax')(attention)
context = dot([attention, encoder_outputs], axes=[2,1])
decoder_outputs = concatenate([context, decoder_outputs])
decoder_dense = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')(decoder_outputs)

# Define the model that will turn
# `encoder_input_data` & `decoder_input_data` into `decoder_target_data`
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_dense)
model.summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

Marco's answer from above works, but one has to change the lines that involve the `dot` function in the second chunk. It takes one positional argument as in `tensorflow`'s example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dot).
Finally, the chunk bellow includes the correction and will work:

```
# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
dec_emb_layer = Embedding(num_decoder_tokens, latent_dim, mask_zero = True)
dec_emb = dec_emb_layer(decoder_inputs)
# We set up our decoder to return full output sequences,
# and to return internal states as well. We don't use the
# return states in the training model, but we will use them in inference.
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(dec_emb, initial_state=encoder_states)
attention = Dot(axes=[2, 2])([decoder_outputs, encoder_outputs])
attention = Activation('softmax')(attention)
context = Dot(axes=[2,1])([attention, encoder_outputs])
decoder_outputs = concatenate([context, decoder_outputs])
decoder_dense = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')(decoder_outputs)

# Define the model that will turn
# `encoder_input_data` & `decoder_input_data` into `decoder_target_data`
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_dense)
model.summary()
```